# Chemical balancer in Java

Tags: java, android, sdk, chemistry

I'm making an app for a chemical formula, and I have made it so that it returns double coefficients.

For example, C6H12O6 + O2 = CO2 + H2O returns .166666667, 1.0, 1.0, and 1.0. I want to write code so that it is 1, 6, 6, and 6 (integers). Also, for another equation, like Ca(OH)2 + H3PO4 = Ca3(PO4)2 + H2O, the return is .5, .333333333, .166666667, and 1.0. It should be 3, 2, 1, and 6. Is there a way I can convert these to integer coefficients in Java?

Answer (score 4):

Do your calculations using a fraction library (like [this one by apache](http://commons.apache.org/math/download_math.cgi)). It will keep the results of your calculations as fractions. You can then use `Fraction.getDenominator()` to find the common one and multiply the rest of your coefficients out by it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate type. In your case, that would be a fraction type which doesn't exist (in the JDK, [Google is your friend](http://www.google.ch/search?q=java+fraction+math)), yet. Go to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29) or [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) to freshen up your knowledge about them.

After you did the balancing, use find the smallest common multiple for all denominators to get integer fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aaron suggests, the rational type is not a Java standard one.

However, there are external libraries providing it, like JScience with its [`Rational`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/Rational.html) type. Unfortunately, there is no information about a potential availability for the Android platform. If it's not the case, try get inspiration from it to create your own rational class.